# Create array of module properties out of array of modules in Terraform

Tags: terraform

In terraform, I have a list

```
  lambda_functions = [
    module.lambda1,
    module.lambda2,
    module.lambda3,
    module.lambda4]
```

(I create Lambdas as modules derived from [serverless.tf Lambda module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda))

I would need to create a separate array like this:

```
  lambda_functions = [
    module.lambda1.this_lambda_function_name,
    module.lambda2.this_lambda_function_name,
    module.lambda3.this_lambda_function_name,
    module.lambda4.this_lambda_function_name]
```

How do I achieve it in Terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation is a typical use-case for [the splat operator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html), `[*]`. It can behave as a shorthand for accessing the same attribute on every element of a list in order to construct a new list.

For example:

```
local.lambda_functions[*].this_lambda_function_name
```

Note that in order to do this you'd need to keep `lambda_functions` as the list of module objects and declare separately this list of names, because the list of names is derived from the list of objects.